# Rails named_scope error in postgreSQL, works in SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, named-scope

I have the following models to associate users with roles:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_role_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :user_roles, :through => :user_role_assignments
end

class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_role_assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :user_role_assignments
end

class UserRoleAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_role

  named_scope :has_admin_role, 
    :joins => :user_role, 
    :conditions => "user_roles.name = 'admin'",
    :group => "user_role_assignments.user_id" 

  named_scope :has_non_admin_role, 
    :joins => :user_role, 
    :conditions => "user_roles.name <> 'admin'",
    :group => "user_role_assignments.user_id" 
end
```

The named scopes in UserRoleAssignment work in SQLite, but not in postgreSQL, which issues this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "user_role_assignments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
: SELECT "user_role_assignments".* FROM "user_role_assignments"   INNER JOIN "user_roles" ON "user_roles".id = "user_role_assignments".user_role_id  WHERE (user_roles.name = 'admin')  GROUP BY user_role_assignments.user_id
```

I have tried many different variations of the named scope (adding a :having clause, adding additional groupings) but each time I add something, a new error arises in postgreSQL so I have reverted back to my original, simple named_scopes. The point of the first scope is to retrieve all users that either have a role with name "admin" and the second is to retrieve users that have some role other than "admin". I use this with searchlogic from other models and it works as expected in SQLite, but not postgreSQL (e.g. User.user_role_assignments_has_admin_role).

How can I modify these named_scopes to work with postgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres is much more picky about GROUP BY clauses than sqlite3.

You'll have to add all of the user_role_assignments column names to your GROUP BY clause:

```
class UserRoleAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_role

  named_scope :has_admin_role, 
    :joins => :user_role, 
    :conditions => "user_roles.name = 'admin'",
    :group => "user_role_assignments.id, user_role_assignments.user_id, user_role_assignments.user_role_id" 

  named_scope :has_non_admin_role, 
    :joins => :user_role, 
    :conditions => "user_roles.name <> 'admin'",
    :group => "user_role_assignments.id, user_role_assignments.user_id, user_role_assignments.user_role_id" 
end
```

If that doesn't work, you can try this next (but I'm not sure if it will work).

```
class UserRoleAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_role

  named_scope :has_admin_role, 
    :joins => :user_role, 
    :conditions => "user_roles.name = 'admin'",
    :group => "user_role_assignments.*" 

  named_scope :has_non_admin_role, 
    :joins => :user_role, 
    :conditions => "user_roles.name <> 'admin'",
    :group => "user_role_assignments.*" 
end
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, but led me to something that does partially. Had to add every column of user_role_assignments to a "select" clause as well. That named scope worked when used from UserRoleAssignments, but didn't work when chained with other models so was ultimately not very useful. I'm in the process of writing named scopes in several different models rather than relying on chaining this one.